# How to render uploaded csv file content as json output on react component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I learned how to create simple react component for my front end development. However, my first react component works, when I tried to render uploaded `csv` file content as `json` output on the console I couldn't produce such output.

**goal**:

I want to render the content of uploaded `csv` file on the server as `json` output. My ultimate goal is I want to pass this `json` output to back end database by fetching REST API.

**my attempt**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class UploadFile  extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }
    uploadFile(event) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);
        if (file) {
          let data = new FormData();
          data.append('file', file);
        }
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div className="Upload">
          <span>
          <input type="file"
          name="myFile"
          onChange={this.uploadFile} />
          </span>
        </div>
      ) 
    }
}
```

can I anyone point me out how to make above react component works properly? How can I render uploaded `csv` file content as `json` output on the server? any idea to make this happen based on above attempt? Thanks in advance!

**update**:

my react component only allows me to browse `csv` file that I want to upload but its content was not rendered anyway. Can anyone help me out how to render uploaded file content as `json` output?

**update 2**:

clarification for my goal: I want user to preview right in browser the jsonified content of the selected csv file, at the same time upload the json to server.

Comment: You need to provide a minimum working example, Stack Overflow is not a "ask for a code site". You need to provide what you have done and what responses are you getting. Look at mozilla developer to start and try something before posting here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: @Marco yes I provide minimum working example above, above react component works but can't render file content as json, above code I didn't include how to render json output because my code didn't work.

Comment: I'm unclear about your expected results vs actual results.  You said you want to render csv as json (which I assume means convert csv to json) *on the server* but you're showing client-side react code.  I'm confused.  It's almost like you're using the word "rendered" differently from how I would use it.  Can you clarify what you mean by "rendered".  Do you just need to set the mime type on the uploaded resource to `application/json`?  Your problem isn't clear to me yet.

Comment: @Wyck problem is above react component didn't render uploaded csv file output on the browser, I wonder how to do that. Yes, I want to parse csv on json with react component. Can you provide any insightful solution? I bet bit more should be added above attempt. Thanks

Comment: So i guess you want user to preview right in browser the json-ified content of the selected csv file, at the same time upload the json to server.

Comment: @hackape exactly, that's what I want. Could you have any insightful solution? Thank you

Comment: Your example does not do anything to the file itself, so it's not a minimum WORKING example. Have you read the link i have provided? It has all the info you need to make it happen.

Comment: @Marco yes it is good source but I want to do it on reactjs component.

Comment: Bro, react uses javascript inside components. Stack Overlfow is a place to learn, not to get code snippets, sorry. You have already all the information you need to do it.

Comment: The technique for reading files locally before uploading them is described with examples here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.  Basically use a FileReader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the react part right. You just don't know how to read the content of a file inside browser. Here's how.

```
readFileContent(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.result;
    const json = csv2json(text);. // find a lib, or write one
    this.setState({ json });
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

The blocker is cleared. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to turn the `json` to some view and render it.

Comment: can you make fully working solution including my part? how to use your function in my component? Yes, I know how to parse csv to json.

Comment: I typed it out on a phone, if miss anything, google `FileReader`

Comment: You declare it as another method of the component, then call it inside `uploadFile` pass that same `file` into it, this is also async method so no worry.

Comment: I lnow nothing about the structure of your json, how am i gonna help you with the view? Plus im typing on mobile phone, just spare me that part pls.

Comment: I left `csv` file and expected json format right here: [json file](https://filebin.net/r1kjputuv501w9ce), could you provide a fully working solution? I am a little lost honestly. Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code authoring service. Show what you've tried before asking for help. You dont tell me you can't render a `<pre>{this.state.json}</pre>`.

Comment: is there any simple way to do `csv2json` for react?