# React website needs reading CSV in the same folder

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I am a newbie studying webengineering. So, this may be a stupid question.

I am now practicing building a simple website by React and try to satisfy the followings.

1. reading CSV file in the same directory in App.js. This CSV file is not uploaded by  tag
2. parsing the CSV file to JSON.
3. displaying a table of the data.

The goal is to display the contents of the CSV file as a table. The CSV is a python-generated file, containing lots of data. I just want to read the CSV and display it as a table.

My react code is now reading the csv as follows,

```
import TestCSV from "./components/Test.csv"
```

And, texting imported TestCSV

```
    const [text, setText] = React.useState();
    fetch(TestCSV)
        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then((textContent) => {
        setText(textContent);
        });
```

parsing,

```
const arr = text.split('\n').map((row) => row.split(','));
```

Then, diplaying the contents,

```
    {(() => {
        const items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j <arr[i].length; j++) {
        items.push(<p>{ arr[i][j] }</p>)
    }}
    return <p>{ items }</p>;
  })()}
```

This code does display the contents of my CSV file. However, I think this is not standard, power play.

Let me know the standard approach to solve what I want to do.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you seen this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55730030/how-to-render-uploaded-csv-file-content-as-json-output-on-react-component